# Python - "IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied" when running cron job but not when running from command line

Tags: python, permissions, cron

I have SSHed from my local machine (a Mac) to a remote machine called “ten-thousand-dollar-bill” as the user “chilge”.

I want to run a Python script in the folder “/afs/athena.mit.edu/c/h/chilge/web_scripts” that generates and saves a .png image to the folder “/afs/athena.mit.edu/c/h/chilge/www/TAF_figures/KORD/1407”. When I run the script from the command line, the image is generated and saved without any issues. When I run the script as cron job, though (the crontab resides in “/afs/athena.mit.edu/c/h/chilge/cron_scripts”), I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> > File "/afs/athena.mit.edu/user/c/h/chilge/web_scripts/generate_plots.py", line 15, in 
> >         save_taffig(taf,fig)
> >
> > File "/afs/athena.mit.edu/user/c/h/chilge/web_scripts/plotting.py", line 928, in save_taffig
> >         fig.savefig(os.getcwd()+'/'+savename+'.png')
> >
> > File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1084, in savefig
> >         self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
> >
> > File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1923, in print_figure
> >         **kwargs)
> >
> > File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 443, in print_png
> >         filename_or_obj = file(filename_or_obj, 'wb')
> >
> > IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/afs/athena.mit.edu/user/c/h/chilge/www/TAF_figures/KORD/1407/140723-1200_AMD_140723-1558.png'

I believe I’ve correctly changed the permissions of all of the necessary directories, but I’m still getting this error. I am not sure why the script would run fine from the command line, but fail when I try to run the script as a cron job.

(Also, I’m not sure if this will be relevant, but don’t have sudo permissions on the remote machine.)

Comment: Are you sure the cron job is running as the same user? Maybe try to print the current username inside your script and see if it's the same as your normal username.

Comment: Same question as pgorsira. Also my two cents: always use `os.path` when you manipulate paths. Also, `open` should be used instead of `file` to open files (and `file` only for type checking).

Comment: Thank you for your replies, pgorsia and Cilyan.

I printed the current username inside the script, and it is the same as my normal username.

Also, I should say that I haven't used `file` to open files in the code I wrote, rather I am calling `pyplot.savefig(savepath)` to save the figure, and I think that might be what is using `file`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an other software opens the file which you want to overwrite?